# How to install acrobat reader 11 in ubuntu 12.04.1 using wine (32 bit system)

Tags: software-installation

I am using ubuntu 12.04.1 (32 bit). I would like to install acrobat reader 11 (32 bit)  using wine. I am unable to install it in my system, since it shows the message "set up is interrupted".

Please help.

Comment: @Mitch: The user wants to know how to install the Windows version, the link you posted shows how to install Adobe Reader from deb repositories.

Comment: What version Wine are you running?

Comment: @Mitch: I am using wine 1.6

Comment: Take a look at https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27093&iTestingId=77234

Comment: You can highlight PDF with Foxit Reader, it's works ok with Wine.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it directly with out wine.Open your terminal and paste these lines.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install acroread
```

[Credit Goes to Noobs lab adobe acrobat treader](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-adobe-acrobat-reader-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: That will install version 9, and not 11.

Comment: @rajagenupula: This will install Acrobat reader 9.5 as adobe didn't release acrobat reader 11 for linux. Acrobat reader 11 has the following features like commenting, highlighting, etc.

Comment: @Mitch: Adobe reader 11 installs completely, but fails to open any file.

Comment: @Mitch: Adobe reader crashes if we use certain tools in annotations saying "This can be caused by a problem or a deficiency in Wine. You may want to check Application database for tips about running the application.

Comment: Try running Acrobat 10.  It that OK?

Comment: Unable to install Acrobat 10. Shows the message setup interupted.

Comment: @Purushothaman give us the complete log purushothaman gaaru

Comment: I have few questions. (1) wine 1.6 default windows version is windows xp, but acrobat does not release 32bit acrobat reader 11  for xp, it released 64 bit and sp3 only. I have used sp3 version for installing acrobat reader 11. Is it correct? (2) Acrobat 11 properly installs but while using certains tools for annotations it crashes.

Comment: @rajagenupula: Log file follows:

Comment: fixme:shell:InitNetworkAddressControl stub
. . .
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:msi:msi_parse_patch_summary patch obsoletes L"{AC76BA86-7AD7-0000-2550-7A8C400A1011}{AC76BA86-7AD7-0000-2550-7A8C400A1012}{AC76BA86-7AD7-0000-2550-7A8C400A1013}"

Comment: err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
. . .
fixme:msi:ITERATE_DuplicateFiles We should track these duplicate files as well
. . .
fixme:msi:ITERATE_CreateShortcuts poorly handled shortcut format, advertised shortcut
fixme:ntdll:NtFsControlFile stub: FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS
. . .
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
. . .
Successfully registered DLL C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 10.0\Reader\authplay.dll